# apache url rewrite on .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to figure out the code on my .htaccess for the following.

Redirect url http://www.mydomain.com/somekw   to http://www.mydomain.com/differentkw
also http://www.mydomain.com/somekw?sort=rating&order=ASC to http://www.mydomain.com/differentkw

I have read up about .htaccess but I have very little skills, hopefully someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule somekw differentkw [L]
```

That will change any instance of `somekw` of `differentkw`. The GET values will stay there.

Just make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled.